# Show inequality of integrals (cauchy-schwarz??)

Tags: integral-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

$f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$ continuous and differentiable and $f(0)=f(1)=0$.
Show that
$$
\left |\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx \right |^2\leq\frac{1}{12}\int_{0}^{1} \left |f'(x)\right|^2dx
$$
Well I know that 
$$
\left |\int f(x)\cdot g(x)\ dx \right|^2\leq \int \left |f(x) \right|^2dx\ \cdot \int \left |g(x) \right |^2dx
$$ 
and I think I should use it, so I guess the term $g(x)$ has to be kind of $\frac{1}{12}$ but I have no idea how I can choose g(x) so that I can show the inequality.

advice?

Comment: $\int_0^1f=-\int_0^1xf'$

Comment: It's to show that the factor is $1/3$. Not sure about $1/12$ though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Integrate by parts to get
$$
\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx = -\int_0^1 (x-1/2)f'(x)\,dx,
$$
and then use Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_0^1 (x-1/2)f'(x)\,dx\right|^2 & \leq \int_0^1(x-1/2)^2\,dx\int_0^1|f'(x)|^2\,dx \\
& = \frac{1}{12}\int_0^1|f'(x)|^2\,dx
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: thank you. i can choose for 1 every antiderivative (x+c) i what? i thought that i can only do this with indefinite integrals, so i guess i was wrong