# Prove the following integral inequality: $\int_{0}^{1}(f''(x))^2dx\ge 1920\left(\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx\right)^2$

Tags: integral-inequality

> Let $f$ be a twice continuously differentiable function from $[0,1]$ into $\mathbb R$. Given that
>   $$f(0)+2f(\frac{1}{2})+f(1)=0,$$
>   show that
>   $$\int_{0}^{1}(f''(x))^2dx\ge 1920\left(\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx\right)^2.$$

I tried some methods, such as Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$\int_{0}^{1}(f''(x))^2dx\cdot\int_{0}^{1}g^2(x)dx\ge\left(\int_{0}^{1}f''(x)g(x)dx\right)^2,$$
where $g(x)$ is polynomial function and $\max{\deg{(g(x))}}\le 2$.

And by parts integral we have
$$\int_{0}^{1}f''(x)g(x)dx=f'(1)g(1)-f'(0)g(0)-f(1)g'(1)+f(0)g'(0)+\int_{0}^{1}f(x)g''(x)dx=
f'(1)g(1)-f'(0)g(0)-f(1)g'(1)+f(0)g'(0)+C\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx.$$

Comment: Use the technique described [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/372033/67609) twice

Comment: A nice question

Answer (score 8):

1. Let $g_1(x)=x(x-1/2)$, $g_2(x)=(x-1)(x-1/2)$. By two integration by parts, we have

$$\int_0^{1/2}f^{\prime\prime}(x)g_1(x)dx=-\frac{f(1/2)+f(0)}{2}+2\int_0^{1/2}f(x)dx$$
and
$$\int_{1/2}^{1}f^{\prime\prime}(x)g_2(x)dx=-\frac{f(1/2)+f(1)}{2}+2\int_0^{1/2}f(x)dx$$
Hence
$$\int_0^{1/2}f^{\prime\prime}(x)g_1(x)dx+\int_{1/2}^{1}f^{\prime\prime}(x)g_2(x)dx=2\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

2. By Cauchy-Schwarz:

$$\left(\int_{0}^{1/2}f^{\prime\prime}(x)g_1(x)dx\right)^2\leq \left(\int_{0}^{1/2}f^{\prime\prime}(x)^2dx\right)\frac{1}{15.2^6}$$

$$\left(\int_{1/2}^{1}f^{\prime\prime}(x)g_2(x)dx\right)^2\leq \left(\int_{1/2}^{1}f^{\prime\prime}(x)^2dx\right)\frac{1}{15.2^6}$$

3. Use now $\sqrt{U}+\sqrt{V}\leq \sqrt{2}\sqrt{U+V}$ with $\displaystyle U=\int_{0}^{1/2}f^{\prime\prime}(x)^2dx$ and $\displaystyle V=\int_{1/2}^{1}f^{\prime\prime}(x)^2dx$ to finish the proof.

Comment: (+1)'ed nice !! $g(x) = \begin{cases} g_1(x) &, x \in [0,1/2] \\ g_2(x) &, x \in [1/2,1] \end{cases}$ is continuous and $f''$ is continuous as well, you could apply CS ineq directly on $g(x)f''(x)$ :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x)$ be the piecewise differentiable function defined as,
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
g_1(x),\quad x\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
g_2(x),\quad x\in\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]
\end{cases}$$
By integration by parts, we find
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}g_1(x)f''(x)\mathrm{d}x
&=g_1(x)f'(x)\bigg|_0^{\frac{1}{2}}-\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}g_1'(x)f'(x)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=g_1(x)f'(x)\bigg|_0^{\frac{1}{2}}-g_1'(x)f(x)\bigg|_0^{\frac{1}{2}}+\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}g_1''(x)f(x)\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1g_2(x)f''(x)\mathrm{d}x
&=g_2(x)f'(x)\bigg|_{\frac{1}{2}}^1-\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1g_2'(x)f'(x)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=g_2(x)f'(x)\bigg|_{\frac{1}{2}}^1-g_2'(x)f(x)\bigg|_{\frac{1}{2}}^1+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1g_2''(x)f(x)\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
First, we need
$g_1''(x)=g_2''(x)=\text{constant}$, so, $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$ are quadratic polynomials
$$\begin{cases}
g_1(x)=cx^2+a_1x+a_0,\quad x\in[0,\frac{1}{2})\\
g_2(x)=cx^2+b_1x+b_0,\quad x\in[\frac{1}{2},1]
\end{cases}$$
Next, Let $$g_1(x)f'(x)\bigg|_0^{\frac{1}{2}}+g_2(x)f'(x)\bigg|_{\frac{1}{2}}^1=0$$
we get,
$$g(1)=g(0)=0\Rightarrow a_0=0,c+b_1+b_0=0 \tag{1}$$
and
$$g_1\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=g_2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}a_1=\frac{1}{2}b_1+b_0\tag{2}$$
Next, Let
$$g_2'(x)f(x)\bigg|_{\frac{1}{2}}^1+g_1'(x)f(x)\bigg|_0^{\frac{1}{2}}=g'(1)f(1)+\left(g_1'\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-g_2'\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-g'(0)f(0)=0$$
Since, $f(0)+2f(\frac{1}{2})+f(1)=0$, we get
$$g_1'\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-g_2'\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=-2g'(0)=2g'(1)$$
so
$$a_1-b_1=-2a_1=4c+2b_1 \tag{3}$$
from $(1),(2),(3)$, we get
$$a_0=0,\quad a_1=-\frac{1}{2}c,\quad b_1=-\frac{3}{2}c,\quad b_0=\frac{1}{2}c$$
Therefore,
$$\int_0^1g(x)f''(x)\mathrm{d}x
=\int_0^1g''(x)f(x)\mathrm{d}x=2c\int_0^1f(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we get
$$\left(2c\int_0^1f(x)\mathrm{d}x\right)^2\leqslant \int_0^1(g(x))^2\mathrm{d}x\int_0^1(f''(x))^2\mathrm{d}x$$
Among,
$$\int_0^1(g(x))^2\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}(g(x))^2\mathrm{d}x+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1(g(x))^2\mathrm{d}x=\frac{c^2}{480}$$
Finally, we get
$$\int_{0}^{1}(f''(x))^2\mathrm{d}x\geqslant 1920\left(\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\mathrm{d}x\right)^2. \tag*{$\Box$}$$