# Where can I learn how to solve integral inequalities?

Tags: integration, reference-request, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

Where could I learn techniques for solving integral inequalities such as

[Given $\int_{\frac13}^{\frac23}f(x)dx=0$, how to prove $4860(\int_0^1f(x)dx)^2\le 11\int_0^1|f''(x)|^2dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3654560/given-int-frac13-frac23fxdx-0-how-to-prove-4860-int-01fxdx2-l?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Prove that $\left|30240\int_{0}^{1}x(1-x)f(x)f'(x)dx\right|\le1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3783034/prove-that-left30240-int-01x1-xfxfxdx-right-le1?noredirect=1&lq=1) ?

One of the posts linked above mentioned polynomial interpolation as a possible approach. Where could I found out more about this idea?

Where do these inequalities come from in general? Many thanks!

Comment: One example is [Wirtinger's inequality for functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger%27s_inequality_for_functions).

Comment: I have seen countless integrals of these flavors and solved many of them in my Olympiad days, but I do not recall a single instance of polynomial interpolation being useful. Most of them are solved by using clever combination of Intermediate Value Theorem, Integration by Parts and Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 1):

You may consult G.H Hardy's famous 'Inequalities'. Though pitched at a much higher level, it's an excellent text. You may obtain the pdf from here:- https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.278938